# Разложение Тейлора

Tags: функции, mathematica

Как построить разложение Тейлора для функции xy=e^y с точностью o(x-x0)^7

Comment: Формулу функции уточните, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+-W(-1%2Fx) 
попробуйте это... Формула выглядит страшно, но это та самая функция, если я ничего не перепутал.